# Error when communicating to azure queues from node.js in a WebRole

Tags: node.js, azure

I am getting this error when trying to create a message on a queue in azure using node.js azure package version 0.6.6:  {"code":"ECONNREFUSED","errno":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect"}

It only happens in the deployed WebRole, but works fine locally and in Azure websites.  I need this to be in a webrole as I need to have an SSL certificate.

I deployed the role using this method: https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/tutorials/getting-started/

An error I see in the logs is this which may help diagnose.

```
Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of null
    at E:\approot\node_modules\azure\lib\services\queue\queueservice.js:295:54
    at Request._callback (E:\approot\node_modules\azure\lib\services\core\serviceclient.js:197:9)
    at E:\approot\node_modules\azure\node_modules\request\main.js:122:22
    at Request.<anonymous> (native)
    at Request.emit (events.js:67:17)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (E:\approot\node_modules\azure\node_modules\request\main.js:224:10)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:67:17)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (http.js:1188:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:67:17)
    at Array.0 (net.js:301:14)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer from posting an issue on the github repo here:

https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-node/issues/434

Answer:
I removed the EMULATED env var from web.config before I published. There was a bug (fixed in the 0.6.7 release) that prevented replacing web.cloud.config for web.config

Thanks markcowl!